# Where is QtWebView / WebView in QtDesigner?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I'm trying to find out where the WebView widget in QtDesigner is. I've installed it (QtDesigner 5.11.1) on OSX Catalina and Win 10. I've installed XCode/C++ libraries along with the open-source QTCreator (all options). I still can't find it.

Comment: It's supposed to be in the "Display Widgets" section. If it's not there, the probable reason is that the development files for the QWebView lib are not installed. You wrote that you installed QtDesigner and QtCreator, but it's unclear how did you install Qt (as the set of libraries and the associated tools like qmake). Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sure. And thank you for replying. Sorry if I gave unclear info. Frustration probably helped to guide that. Anyhoo....

QtDesigner I downloaded and installed from here:build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

Comment: QtCreator I downloaded from qt.io. 
PyQt5 was downloaded through PyCharm.

Comment: I duplicated the process on Windows thinking it was an OS specific problem. 

But wait - there's more....
Do I need to run Anaconda for QT to work?

Comment: I just saw an error message that referenced anaconda. I'm going to try that. 

My goal is to build a browser that helps with my tasks at work. I am part of a 6 person team that manages 400+ high-profile websites in DC.

Answer (score 0):

QWebView unfortunately is not part of the official Qt installers since Qt 5.6, because it has been obsoleted by QWebEngineView (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html).
Several 3rdparty Qt installers (like most of the Linux distributions, msys2 on Windows) still ship the QWebView module as well. This leaves you with 2 options: either migrating to QWebEngineView, or installing Qt from one of these 3rdparty installers.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'll look into that and report back.